# Common integer roots of polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory, mathematical-software

I have two polynomials of form
$$f_1(w,x)=M_1$$
$$f_2(y,z)=M_2$$
and I have two polynomials of form
$$g_1(w,x,y,z)=M_3$$
$$g_2(w,x,y,z)=M_4$$
where $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2\in\mathbb Z[w,x,y,z]$ and $M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4\in\mathbb Z$ holds and $w,x,y,z$ are variables.

I also know

1. $w^2,x^2,y^2,z^2<c\max_{i,j}(|M_i|\|f_j\|_\infty,|M_i|\|g_j\|_\infty)$ at a $c>0$ where $\|f_j\|_\infty,\|g_j\|_\infty$ are maximum absolute values of polynomial coefficients.
2. $\mathsf{deg}(\mathsf{GCD}(f_i,g_j))\neq0$ holds. So if $\mathsf{GCD}(M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4)=M>1$ then modulo $M$ the system is not algebraically independent which is also the case over $\mathbb C$ if $M_1=M_2=M_3=M_4=0$.

I want to test if the system is algebraically independent and if so I want to extract the common integer roots for $w,x,y,z$.

What is the best way to do this and are there any software?

Comment: In Mathematica, you can try FindInstance: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html

Comment: Well I am looking for some algorithm that is already implemented and known to be efficient. I don't know what mathematica implemented. I have tried mathematica before and it hangs.

Comment: Why do you think that there is an efficient algorithm? There may be no algorithm at all to determine if four polynomials in four variables have a common integer zero.

Comment: Oh ok. May I ask if the polynomials are algebraically independent then is there a bound in number of solutions?